# Particular series on Hilbert Space

Tags: sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces

Let $(H, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ a Hilbert space and consider a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $H$ such that:
$$\langle x_n,x_m\rangle\ =\ \delta_{mn}\ =\ \left\{\begin{array}{ll}1, & n = m\\0, & n\neq m\end{array}\right.$$
Show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle x,x_n\rangle|^2\ \leq\ \|x\|^2,\ \forall x\in H.$$
Moreover, given a scalar sequence $\{\alpha_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, show that the following are equivalent:

1. $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_nx_n$ converge in $H$.
2. $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_n|^2 < +\infty$

Comment: Is this homework? Have a look for Bessels inequality.

Comment: Yes is a homework and I didn't know that this problem is about the Bessels inequality. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some hints: let $F_N$ be the subspace generated by $\{x_1,\dots,x_N\}$. It's a closed subspace of $H$. So we can consider the projection over this subspace. This gives that $\sum_{n=1}^N|\langle x,x_n\rangle|^2\leqslant \lVert x\rVert^2$.

For the equivalence, you can compute the norm of the partial sums.

Comment: When I try to prove form b) to a), I have that $$\left\|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_nx_n\right\| = \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_n|^2\right)^{1/2} < +\infty.$$ How I can justify that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_nx_n$ converge on $H$?

Comment: Show that the sequence of partial sums is Cauchy.

Comment: I proved that $$\left\|\sum_{k=n}^m\alpha_kx_k\right\| = \left(\sum_{k=n}^m|\alpha_k|^2\right)^{1/2},$$ then as $m>n\rightarrow \infty$, is correct to say that $\left\|\sum\limits_{k=n}^m\alpha_kx_k\right\| \rightarrow 0$ because $\sum\limits_{k=n}^m|\alpha|^2$ is bounded?

Comment: It's because the latest quantity you mention _converges to $0$_, not only because it is bounded.

Comment: I see that, but then, Where I did use the boundedness?

Comment: Oh I see, you meant the boundedness of $\sum_{k=n}^m|\alpha_k|^2$ and that's what you used to see the convergence to $0$ (the remainder of a convergent series).

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I have already shown almost everything, I just have to prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_n x_n$ is convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_n|^2$ is also convergent, how can I do this? Any ideas? Thank you very much for your help.